# What is the life time of data's stored in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to know the life time of table data's which is stored in android sqlite database. Here my requirement is I want to keep all of my table vales until app un-installed. If we can not achieve this in sqlite then kindly recommend some other idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data will remain in SQLite database till you uninstall the application OR you do a clear Data from Settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite is persistent storage, it will stay there until you or the user deletes it.

Comment: I guess my answer was unclear in the sense that I said "you" instead of "you or the user" 

Either way, its persistent storage,

Comment: Damian, you know you should edit your answer to make it clearer then, or delete it outright. Comments are a poor substitute for making an answer clearer.

Answer (score -1):

The data persists, until and unless the application is Uninstalled from Android System.